# Font module error when using pygame2exe

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I used [Pygame2exe](http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe) from the Pygame website and that got rid of the problem with the `.dlls` but there's still an error that remains.
The only font I'm using is the standard pygame font (`freesansbold.ttf`) and I've included a copy of it in my game directory.
**Also,**
I'm using the `Font` class and not the SysFonts class which I thought would fix my problem.
Any thoughts?

```
C:\Python26\apple_orchard\dist\appleorchard.exe:27: RuntimeWarning: use font: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd
(ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "appleorchard.py", line 165, in <module>
  File "appleorchard.py", line 27, in __init__
  File "pygame\__init__.pyo", line 70, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks like very similar to this one : http://thadeusb.com/weblog/2009/4/15/pygame_font_and_py2exe

Try to add `"sdl_ttf.dll"` to the list of system dlls like this :

```
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL # save the orginal before we edit it
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    # checks if the freetype and ogg dll files are being included
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("libfreetype-6.dll", "libogg-0.dll", "sdl_ttf.dll"):
            return 0
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname) # return the orginal function
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL # override the default function with this one
```

Comment: Thanks!  There's no way I would've figured that out on my own! :P